# How can I hide my mac address when using a public wifi?

Tags: wifi, vpn, openvpn, mac-address, raspberry-pi

As a new student of cyber security, I have started to see in real-time how an individual can actually scan and view the mac addresses on a public wifi connection.

How can I hide my mac address when using a public wifi connection? Please I mean aside from not using public wifi at all.

Also, I am very DIY, but I am still unclear how VPNs work. I have skim read about setting it up on one's own server, but not sure how that works in conjunction with using wifi, so any documentation would help. I still have a lot to learn about OpenVPN, SSH Tunnel, RaspianVPNs. I know of them, so just tossing these out as answers would not help. I guess I am looking for a how-to than just use this...okay, but how? Anyway, thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to hide your MAC address before connecting to open wifi?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/153594/is-it-possible-to-hide-your-mac-address-before-connecting-to-open-wifi), [How to stay anonymous in public wireless network?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47262/how-to-stay-anonymous-in-public-wireless-network)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is you **can't** hide your MAC address completely since it's essential in networking. As per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address):

> MAC addresses are used in the medium access control protocol sublayer of the data link layer.

What you can do though is to [spoof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_spoofing) your MAC address so you don't "expose" the manufacturer of your computer's network card which is going to help you avoid targeted attacks. Also as @multithr3at3d correctly pointed out, by spoofing you MAC address you also prevent your MAC address from being used to track you.

Comment: It's not really the manufacturer that you want to hide; you just want to prevent your MAC address from being used to track you.